# Where can i find the Microsoft Kinect API list similar to the one in java doc?

Tags: c#, api, sdk, kinect

Where can I find the Microsoft Kinect SDK API list for C# similar to the one provided in Java Docs where it consists of all the Classes, Packages...etc in the SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ and C#/VB.NET reference documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572480.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try here, googling on kinect microsoft sdk msdn should have been enough to find it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.aspx